# Remove old puppet repo configuration

Tags: puppet, yum

I want to consolidate my repository into a new repository structure and I have this working in Puppet. However, the old yum repository information still remains on the nodes. Can puppet force the removal of the old yum repository information? How do you do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to use a `file` resource with `ensure => absent`, as in

```
file { '/etc/yum.repos.d/crufty.repo':
  ensure => absent,
}
```

It doesn't look as if the `yumrepo` resource type supports removal (although you could set `enabled => false`, which in practice would get you the same behavior).